# How to Upload image in Dotnet?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Iam trying to upload but does not work with me
how i fixed it ??
the Cropper work but the save function does not work

Controller

```
public class CropperController : BaseController
    {
       private IHostingEnvironment Environment;
 
    public CropperController(IHostingEnvironment _environment)
        {
            Environment = _environment;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(List<IFormFile> postedFiles)
        {
            string wwwPath = this.Environment.WebRootPath;
            string contentPath = this.Environment.ContentRootPath;

            string path = Path.Combine(this.Environment.WebRootPath, "Uploads");
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }

            List<string> uploadedFiles = new List<string>();
            foreach (IFormFile postedFile in postedFiles)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, fileName), FileMode.Create))
                {
                    postedFile.CopyTo(stream);
                    uploadedFiles.Add(fileName);
                    ViewBag.Message += string.Format("<b>{0}</b> uploaded.<br />", fileName);
                }
            }

            return View();
        }
```

why does not work

How to Upload image in Dotnet ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of uploading an image;

Html Section:

```
<input id="MyImage" name="postedFiles[]" accept=".jpeg,.jpg,.png" type="file" multiple/>
```

Model:

```
public Class ImageUpload{
   public string ImagUrl {get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SaveImage(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> postedFiles)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string[] path;
            string pic = "";
            string physicalPath;
            int i = 0;

            if (postedFiles != null)
            {
                path = new string[postedFiles.Count()]
                foreach (HttpPostedFileBase image in postedFiles)
                {
                    if(image != null)
                    {
                        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(image.FileName);
                        if (fileExtension.ToLower() != ".jpeg" && fileExtension.ToLower() != ".jpg" && fileExtension.ToLower() != ".png")
                        {
                            return view();
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Images/UploadedIMage")))
                {
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/Images/UploadedIMage"));
                }

                foreach (HttpPostedFileBase img in postedFiles)
                {
                    if (img != null)
                    {
                        pic = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(img.FileName);
                        physicalPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/UploadedIMage"), pic);
                        path[i] = "/Images/UploadedIMage/" + pic;
                        img.SaveAs(physicalPath);

                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            foreach (var url in path)
            {
                ImageUpload imageupload = new ImageUpload();
                imageupload.ImagUrl = url;
                _db.ImageUpload .Add(imageupload);
                _db.SaveChanges();
            }

        }

        return view();
    }
```